# better format using nanodbc R on Windows

Tags: sql-server, odbc, date-format, r

Using R-3.5 and [`odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) (which uses [`nanodbc`](https://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc)), I connect via ODBC and the `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` ODBC driver on windows 10.

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(odbccon, "select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as now")
#                                         now
# 1 2018-09-03 16:36:44 Pacific Standard Time
```

The same query with a native (non-ODBC) driver:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(nativecon, "select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as now")
#                                  now
# 1 2018-09-03 19:37:13.9923643 -04:00
```

(Both are R's `character` type.)

This demonstrates a few things:

- the ODBC driver does not recognize an object of type `DATETIMEOFFSET`, which an [issue I've raised with `odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/207); this is not of itself a huge issue, but I think indicates why it is returned as a string (and not internally converted correctly, I think)
- loss of millisecond precision (the biggest problem)
- non-standard time zone indication (where I believe "standard" includes `-07:00`, `-0700`, `+07`, or even `America/Los_Angeles`)

Is there a way to prevent SQL Server or Windows ODBC from formatting (and losing) data thus? Is there a way to change this via a SQL Server command, an ODBC function, or something else? (The largest problem is omission of milliseconds.)

**Edit**: for fairness, having it come as a `character` vice a native `POSIXt` is not a big problem, that's easy enough to fix with a call to `as.POSIXct`; similarly, I can compensate for the timezone depiction using a lookup on something built from [this "Zone -> Tzid" table](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html). It's the loss-of-data thing I really need to mitigate, since my immediate use-case uses milli-second precision, and altering all processes to explicitly `cast(...)` is more than I'd like to do right now (and is not a general solution).

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select @@VERSION")
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# 1 Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64) \n\tJul  5 2017 23:41:17 \n\tCopyright (c) Microsoft Corporation\n\tStandard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )\n
```